# Ruby on Rails: Saving a model twice yields two records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model "Food" and I create it using:

```
food= Food.new
food.attributes = attributeHash
food.save #creates 1 new record
```

Now, when it's saved, immediately, I do:

```
food.json = food.to_json
food.save #creates another record! Why???
```

This creates another record with the ID(primary key) incremented by 1. I expected it to just update the record already inserted. I swore I did this once before and it worked, so am I doing it wrong here? Am I getting expected behavior?

Comment: I created my own test case with the code above and it just modified the existing object. It didn't create two. Is there anything about your setup that might be different?  What version of Rails are you using? Does your Food model have special logic in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing two `#save()`'s in a row without calling `food#json=`, maybe there's something in that setter that's creating a new object.